# ANDROID: Custom view implemtation

Tags: android, user-interface, view

I have a custom view. When will android call draw() on it? After it calls onMeasure and onLayout?

```
'package global.domination.pack;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class TileView extends View {

    // rules about what can be and is on this tile
    boolean bLand;
    boolean bSea;
    boolean bAir;
    boolean bOccupied;
    Character _character;

    // this tile's coordinates
    int nX;
    int nY;

    // bitmaps used for drawing this tile
    Bitmap _originalBitmap;
    Bitmap _finalBitmap;

    // this constructor initializes all variables (creates the tile)
    public TileView(Context context, boolean isLand, boolean isSea, boolean isAir, boolean isOccupied, int x_Coordinate, int y_Coordinate, Bitmap bitmap) {
        super(context);

        //Initialize variables and set tile graphic.
        bLand           = isLand;
        bSea            = isSea;
        bAir            = isAir;
        bOccupied       = isOccupied;
        nX              = x_Coordinate;
        nY              = y_Coordinate;
        _originalBitmap = bitmap;
        _character      = null;
        _finalBitmap    = bitmap;
    }


    /* This method is called by parent view when it 
     * wants to know this view's drawing preferences
     */
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // set this tiles dimensions
        this.setMeasuredDimension(50, 50);
    }

    /* This method is called by parent view when it wants 
     * this view to draw itself.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {      
        // attempt to draw the _finalBitmap (tile graphic with character graphic)
        try{
            canvas.drawBitmap(_finalBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        }
        catch(RuntimeException rtException){
            Log.e("EXCEPTION", "ERROR DRAWING FINAL BITMAP" + rtException.getMessage() , rtException);
        }               
    }
}
'
```

Comment: Please add some code snippet to understand more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Are you overriding the `onMeasure()` of the `ViewGroup`s?  If so you need to remember to call `measure()` on you child views.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes my custom ViewGroup (which this view is added to) calls measure() on it like it's suppose to. onMeasure() and onLayout() complete as expected, but draw() is never called.

Answer (score 0):

`onMeasure()` is always called whenever a view have to measure dimensions of its own and child views.
If you are going to implement the viewgroup then its child view's `onDraw()` method will be called whenever a viewgroup has to dispatch draw event to all its childs after `onLayout()`.

Here is a image link which may help you understanding view lifecycle flow:

[image: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9UCoqk4eOYs/UXOXi4Gqy5I/AAAAAAAAAG4/A8z6ociZjPY/s1600/android.png]

For brief description you may read [the official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components).